# Various ways of saying OK?

Tags: word-choice, culture, verbs

I mean OK as in said in agreement with what someone has suggested.

> A: We should go to the park. 
> B: OK.

If someone used the verb 不 verb structure I would think you should use the same verb in expressing agreeement but is this true for all cases, notably "好“？

> A: 我们去公园吧。
>  B: 好 or 行 or ？？

Comment: Ah, but so many...

Comment: @congliu Exactly, but are they all interchangeable?English  also has many; OK, sure, yeah, all right, why not? etc. but there are differences in register and situation.

Comment: not only different words, but also the difference given by specific tones, combination with gestures, and context, to name just a few. Sorry I can't give a thorough conclusion here, what I can do is just tell my opinion to someone's answer.

Comment: The part about verb 不 verb structure seems to have gotten lost.  Can you even use that structure to make a suggestion this way?  Can you say

Comment: My editor aborted my comment, sorry.  I mean to ask can you reply 好 to a question 我们去不去公园?  Can such a question be used as a suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are loose translations:

好的 = alright!

好吧 = okay, fine... (Kind of like... going along with it)

好啊 = sure! (As Wendy said... a bit more of an upbeat tone)

好 = Okay.

行 = Sure. I guess that works

恩　= Colloquial form of grunting in agreement... kind of like a verbal nod of approval

可以/可以啊 = I can/Sure!

Or, if you agree with what someone said... You can repeat the verb, or similar verb (in this case replace 去 (go) with 走　(walk)):

```
A: 我们去公园吧！ 
B: 走啊！
```

Comment: Nice try! Add something based on my experience: 恩 has some variants: 1) 嗯 2) 嗯嗯 3) 蒽 ... 好 has some other variants: 1) 好嘀 2) 好嘞 3) 好嘛 4) 好好好 5) 好的呢 ...

Comment: what if we want to use something in an application like OK button for Chinese? What character is used in place of OK ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually 好，行 all works in this situation. No big difference but I slightly prefer 好, cuz 行 implying some sense that you allow this to happen, while 好 is a happy agreement.

If you want be more delightful, you may want to try 好啊！

hope this will help.

Comment: Depends on the tone, 行 can perfectly give the sense of "happy agreement" too, e.g. a high toned 行啊!

Answer (score 1):

1，可以 is another choice. so are 可以啊，可以呀。

Answer (score 1):

好

行

可以

嗯

嗯哪

必须滴

当然

可不

中

成

愿意

承当

赞

可

然

然也

不辞

遵命

喳

诺

允

准

Comment: 喳? 然也? Going retro? Some elaboration would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, in order for your answer to be useful please expand your answer to include some English explanation of each of the items above.

Comment: also in classical Chinese, 大善

Comment: you forgot: 要得!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget

1. 没问题 No problem
2. 可以撒 sure
3. 走起 sure, let's go

:D